# How to make a graph with X-Y scale to accommodate a set of 2D points?

Tags: iphone, algorithm, graph

I have a graph to be displayed in an iphone in landscape and portrait mode.
I have a set of points stored in a collection in terms of portrait mode.
I have done calculations to make them appear in the same manner on landscape as well.

My problem is I need to plot numbers on X and Y axis and plot the points **according to that of graph** and **not the screen coordinates I captured.**

and more  importantly, **the scale and numbers on X-Y axis should be generated to accomodate every point in that collection** such that nothing goes out of the bounds of the screen/graph.

Size in pixels of the grids remain the same in landscape/portrait.

**Only the scale changes. but the change should also be such that points are in multiples of 5,10,100,150 etc.**
How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You need to calculate a scale. First find max and min points value, then calculate `pointsDifference = abs(maxPoint - minPoint)`, then `pixelsDifference =` your avaliable space for graph in pixels. Then `scale = pixelsDifference / pointsDifference;` You can take same scale for box axes or different. And after that you can simple accomodate points.

Comment: > First find max and min points value < : what is a point's value ? + is the "available space for graph", its area (width * height) ?